# Sitewide page on all the blogs in the network

Tags: pages, multisite, blog

I have WordPress multisite installed. And i need to make it so that a page called (Company Ideas) on the main blog is added to new blogs created on the network.

So once someone registers a new blog. The page called (Company Ideas) from the main blog will be added to the new blog that was created and the page will be updated from the main blog

Kind of like a sitewide page called (Company Ideas) controlled by the Super Admin from the main blog

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're looking for a post or page broadcaster that can help you push post or page creation and update to your multisite blogs. Give these plugins a try:

[ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/)

<strike>[Multipost MU](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/)</strike>
<sup>(dead link, mirror at the [Internet Archive : Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110722095739/http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One of the best plugins for Sitewide Tags, and its well supported is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/ developed by @donncha (of WP Super Cache fame)

The plugin has many features including

- pull posts and pages from all sites
- create a 'trending' blog or publish to the main site
- pull in custom fields like images
- ignore private blogs (and ignore pages)
- can be modified to include custom post types

I've been using it for years ... you can see it in action at http://wordpress.damien.co and http://damien.co

Ron and Andrea Rennick (Andrea 'admins' the Multsite forum on WP.org) have a number of free additional plugins like recent posts, recent members which all work with Sitewide Tags